# PHP – validate a form before the file uploads

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have an HTML form with a file input, submitted by AJAX to `upload.php`. The PHP script performs a number of tests to detect invalid submissions, e.g., checking an encrypted timestamp, and will either return an error or process the uploaded file.

The question is: Is it possible to perform the server-side tests and return an error before the server receives the entire file? This would save time and bandwidth.

Comment: How about the file upload is only set to be available on a successful return from the AJAX? So the ajax is needed to post and get a reply before then allowing the setting of a file to upload?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I will do. I was hoping for a way to do it with one POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you have one form with ascii data and binary (uploads), it's 1 request. The uploads will be stored in the temp directory of the server till you move them.

But, you can do 2 things:

- Check cientside and start upload if check is ok
- Extract the upload function from the rest of the post. So you can for example upload in the 'background', check on server side, etc., completely separated from the rest of your form and submit.

I prefer no. 2. It's very good for your performance and user experience (e.g. for large files).